# Integer Logic - Prime and Unique Factorization Proof

Tags: prime-factorization, integers

I could use some help with this problem:

> Let *a*, *b*  ∈ Z (integer set) such that (*a*, *b*) = 1.
>   Suppose that *ab* = $x^2$ for some x in Z (integer set). Prove that a = $y^2$ and b = $z^2$ for some *y* and *z* in Z(integer set).

Because of (a, b) = 1, I assume a and b have no common factors.

So *a* can be written as *a* = $p_1, p_2, p_3... p_s$ where *p* is any positive integer. Same goes for *b* = $q_1, q_2, q_3...q_s$ where *q* is any positive integer.

Since *ab* = $x^2$, it can be said that $x^2$ = ( $p_1, p_2, p_3... p_s$)($q_1, q_2, q_3...q_s$) = ab

And I get lost from here... I think it is only possible for this to be true if and only if all the exponent variables are even numbers. Could any help me elaborate on this?

Comment: almost true, and it is true if everything is positive. Otherwise, you could have $a=-y^2, \; \; b = -z^2 $